# JDBC Connection Pool

Tags: java, jdbc

What is the state-of-the-art in [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) [connection pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) libraries?

Years ago the [`Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) library was developed as an alternative for highly-threaded environments because of weaknesses in the [`Apache Commons DBCP`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/). Now I see that a new version (DBCP2) has been built using a new version 2 of [`Apache Commons Pool`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/), another library specially built to support implementing various object-pooling projects.

There are some other libraries, but I don't know their current state:

- [ViburCP](http://www.vibur.org)
- [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/)
- [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/)
- [BoneCP](http://www.jolbox.com)

Please give pros and cons of the various choices for use in a highly-threaded [Java Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet) environment with relational databases such as [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org) or [H2 Database Engine](http://www.H2Database.com/).

My own priorities are:

- Proper JDBC behavior
- Reliability (robust in a highly-threaded environment)
- Easy to install & manage
- Simple, minimal tuning required for general usage

Hyper-speed, such a being good at benchmark testing, is *not* important. Tolerating rapid turnover of briefly-used connections in likely contention within a highly-threaded environment is my only performance concern.

[JMX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Management_Extensions) or other runtime-management/supervision access is a bonus.

I'm currently using the `Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool` with Tomcat 8 and Postgres on Java 8 with no problems. I'm just wondering if that is still the best option. The reviews I’ve found by googling seem to be quite a few years old. I am not using [Hibernate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_(Java)) or any other [object-relational mapper (ORM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) nor JPA technology; I just hand-write SQL code in JDBC.

What is a good JDBC connection pool library for my needs?

Comment: What did decide to go with? And how did you make your decision?

Comment: @JeevanPatil웃 Long story short, do not necessarily use connection pooling. Building a pool properly is surprisingly difficult. Even if done right, you can have problems such as a transaction left pending in a connection you just got from pool. If getting a connection to a DB server on same machine, performance is quite fast and does not justify using a pool in knee-jerk fashion without further consideration.  Use simple direct connections without a pool until you know you have a demonstrable performance issue. If you hold a connection for extended use, even less need for pool.